# Ослабляется ли значение сказуемого?

Tags: сказуемые

Ослабляется ли значение сказуемого-существительного при инверсии? Расширяются ли границы сказуемого в этом случае?

*Муся — кошка умная. Версаль — дворец удивительный.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Ослабляется ли значение сказуемого-существительного при инверсии?
```

Можно и так сказать. Ослабляется назывная функция, возникает указательная.

> [Прилагательное при существительном в составе сказуемого может быть в качестве ремы вынесено в предложении в заключающую позицию. Такая актуализация обычна при словах, выполняющих указательную (местоименную) функцию: (см. § 2327, п. 2б): Прием Гумбольдта в Москве и в университете был дело нешуточное (Герц.); Бонифацио - городок удивительный (Кавер.); Строительство моста - дело всегда недешевое и хлопотное (Песк.).](http://rusgram.narod.ru/2330-2352.html#2340) (РГ-80,  § 2340).
>
> [Так в предложении возникает своеобразная местоименная функция
> существительного-сказуемого, а основная информативная нагрузка при
> этом падает на обязательное в этих случаях определяющее слово: Правда - понятие не абстрактное; Историзм - всепроникающая категория; Болгария - небольшая страна; Десять лет - срок достаточный...](http://rusgram.narod.ru/2306-2329.html#2327) (РГ-80, § 2327).

```
Расширяются ли границы сказуемого в этом случае?
```

Нет. Сказуемое остается прежним по составу "нулевая связка + неразложимое сочетание (сущ. + прил.)".

Comment: Имелось в виду, входит ли прилагательное в этом случае.

Comment: Да. Об этом в скобках - "нулевая связка + неразложимое сочетание (сущ. + прил.)".

Comment: А разве при прямом порядке слов прилагательное будет не определением?

Comment: У сказуемого не бывает определений. Только именная часть (сущ., прил., прич.) в составе сложного именного сказуемого. У вас ведь не предложение "Умная Муся - это кошка".

Comment: Насколько я знаю, определений не бывает у глагола-сказуемого. Но существительное...

Comment: https://russkiiyazyk.ru/question/opredelenie-ot-skazuemogo

Comment: Да, если мы о вообще всех сказуемых-существительных (не из вашего вопроса). Чтобы различить, где определение, а где именная часть, формальных признаков нет - только семантика. Об этом РГ-80, §2324 (про "два больших семантических класса"). Ваш пример - первый класс, § 2325, 3 или §2327, 2б. Только в нем есть сказ.-существительные с местоименной ролью (при них прилагательное становится неотделимой частью сказуемого). Пример по ссылке - думаю, первый класс, §2325, 1.

Comment: Порядок слов играет роль, семантика - второстепенное.

Comment: Ну, русская грамматика так не считает. В уже приведенной мной цитате "Прилагательное... может быть... вынесено в предложении в заключающую позицию" - а не обязано быть вынесено. + Примеры приводятся без различения порядка слов.

Comment: Посмотрите пример из Розенталя про "тире". Там указаны основы, и предшествующее сказуемому прилагательное не выделяется в качестве основы.

Comment: Приведете, посмотрю.

Comment: "Иванов — хороший шахматист"

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/142067/discussion-between-atoma-and-ajgy).

Answer (score 1):

**Непонятливый ученик**

**Про кошку Мусю. Школьное сочинение.**

У нас есть кошка, ее зовут Муся.  Муся ― умная кошка.

Нет, лучше так: У нас есть кошка, ее зовут Муся.  Муся ― кошка умная.

― И что, это всё твое сочинение?

― Нет, еще сказуемое надо найти. В первом случае это «умная кошка», а во втором  ― «кошка умная».

― Молодец! Все правильно.  Сказуемое остается прежним по составу "нулевая связка + неразложимое сочетание (сущ. + прил.). Тебе все понятно?

― Да, все.  Я только не понимаю, **почему это сочетание  неразложимое**? Нам учительница говорила, что неразложимым считается сочетания "котенок с белыми лапками".

― И что с того? Таких сочетаний много, в одном вашем учебнике обозначено 8 групп.

― Ну еще: ***актеры — люди интересные; скрипка — вещь деликатная***. А Муся, как мне кажется, сюда плохо подходит. Может быть, у нее семантическая недостаточность не такая?  Например, **не постоянная, а контекстуальная**.

Comment: В корне не согласен с вами. При прямом порядке слов перед сказуемым будет стоять определение, а не прилагательное-сказуемое. Пример из Розенталя: "Тире ставится между подлежащим и сказуемым при отсутствии связки, если оба главных члена предложения выражены существительными в форме именительного падежа: Одиночество в творчестве — тяжёлая штука (Ч.)"

Comment: Я всегда уважаю чужое мнение. Неразложимое сочетание- это тема грамматики, а не интонационного членения предложения на группу подлежащего и группу сказуемого. , которое зависит от многих факторов. В какой современной литературе по грамматике встречается  термин "прилагательное-сказуемое"?  Почему это сочетание неразложимое? Вы можете указать источник? Спасибо.

Comment: Прилагательным-сказуемым я его сейчас для простоты понимания обозначил. Я правильно понял, что с Розенталем в выделении таких основ вы, получается, не согласны?

Comment: Вопрос ведь был не в разложимых сочетаниях, а  именно в группе сказуемого.

Comment: Состав группы сказуемого не меняется, но смысловой центр смещается на прилагательное. Это обычное дело при инверсии, для этого она и делается. А где у Розенталя сказано про такие основы?

Comment: Если состав не меняется, то подлежащее и сказуемое будут одинаковыми в разных примерах:  "Иванов - хороший шахматист/Иванов - шахматист хороший". Тогда как вы объясните то, что Розенталь не выделяет прилагательное в первое случае как сказуемое?

Comment: Подлежащее и сказуемое выделены жирным шрифтом.

Comment: Здесь надо разбираться, так как предикативная основа - вещь серьезная.  Значит, это  все-таки неразложимое сочетание, если прилагательное входит в   сказуемое?  Под грамматическое определение таких сочетаний не очень подходит. Впрочем, я не настаиваю., если вы уверены в своей правоте.  Меня интересовала именно тема неразложимых сочетаний, не более того.  Кстати, мне не очень нравится изучать грамматику по Розенталю.

Comment: Случай, о котором вы говорите (где предшествующее сказуемому прилагательное также является сказуемым), я видел только в одном учебнике - Кустовой. Пример там достаточно странный: он хороший человек. Автор выделяет "хороший" как сказуемое. Возможно, это касается отдельных групп слов.

Comment: Я, честно говоря, не вижу в этой фразе неразложимого сочетания. Все же это не "юноша с голубыми глазами". Мне кажется, все дело в  смысловых акцентах.

Comment: Мне тоже  так кажется, просто принятый вами ответ показался мне противоречивым. Цитирую: Расширяются ли границы сказуемого в этом случае?
Нет. Сказуемое остается прежним по составу "нулевая связка + неразложимое сочетание (сущ. + прил.)"..

Comment: Меня интересовала именно эта инверсия. Просто я думал, что включение в состав сказуемого прилагательного возможно только при словах с более-менее абстрактным значением: мужчина, вещь, штука, дело. В данном случае опорные слова имеют полноценное значение, но все равно прилагательное включается в состав, именно это и нужно было узнать.

Comment: Вы,кстати, не ответили на мой вопрос в "неполных предложениях".